# Haskell function to check if substring "100" is present in the binary expansion of a decimal number

Tags: haskell

Define a function nohundred :: Int -> Int such that for a positive number n   nohundred n is the nth positive number such that "100" does not occur as a substring in its binary expansion.

```
decToBin :: Int -> [Int]
decToBin x = reverse $ decToBin' x
  where
    decToBin' :: Int -> [Int]
    decToBin' 0 = []
    decToBin' y = let (a,b) = quotRem y 2 in [b] ++ decToBin' a
check :: [Int] -> Bool
check (z:zs)
  |((z == 1) && (head (zs) == 0) && (head (tail zs) == 0)) = True
  | otherwise                                              = check zs

binToDec :: [Int] -> Int
binToDec l = sumlist (zipWith (*) (iterate f 1) (reverse l))
  where
    sumlist :: [Int] -> Int
    sumlist [] = 0
    sumlist (x:xs) = x + (sumlist xs)
    f :: Int -> Int 
    f j = (2 * j)
nohundred :: Int -> Int
nohundred n = if ((check fun) == True) then (binToDec (fun)) else (nohundred (n+1))
  where
    fun = decToBin n
```

The above code gives error :-

```
*Main> nohundred 10
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list...
```

The desired output is 14.

```
*Main> nohundred 100
100
```

The desired output is 367...
Can anyone suggest the cause of error?

Comment: Avoid `head,tail`, they are dangerous. Prefer (exhausive) patter matching whenever possible, and turn on warnings with `-Wall` so that GHC can warn about missing cases.

Comment: In case you want more test cases, ```nohundred m = [ n | n <- [1..], not ("100" `isInfixOf` showIntAtBase 2 intToDigit n "") ] !! (m - 1)``` is a reference implementation (you'll need to import `Numeric`, `Data.Char`, and `Data.List`).

Comment: Can you be more precise with your bracketing please @Alec

Comment: @ShubhamKumar I'm not sure I understand. You can literally copy-paste in the one line I gave into GHCi and it will define the function you want (after importing `Numeric` `Data.Char`, and `Data.List`, of course)

Comment: ``any ((==4) . (`mod` 8)) . takeWhile (>0) . iterate (`div` 2)``

Answer (score 2):

This function is partial:

```
check (z:zs)
  |((z == 1) && (head (zs) == 0) && (head (tail zs) == 0)) = True
  | otherwise                                              = check zs
```

When called with a one- or two-element list, the first check will call `head` on an empty list. Additionally, it does not cover the empty-list case. The idiomatic way to write this is:

```
check (1:0:0:zs) = True
check (z:zs) = check zs
check [] = False
```

Additionally, your `nohundred` function takes a number and finds the next higher non-hundred number; but you want the nth non-hundred number, which is a very different thing.